# I want the cursor to appear in the Entry -Or Editor- when the Entry is touched and not when the click on it ends

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, maui

When I click on a character in the entry using TapGestureRecognizer, I want to store the cursor position in a variable, but the cursor appears after executing the TapGestureRecognizer event, in this case it will not give me the correct position, so I want the cursor to appear first and then execute the TapGestureRecognize event, I also wish I could do this with a Editor (I want this on Android)

When I clicked on the entry, I was expecting to store the location of the cursor at this click at the same time, but what happened to me was the opposite, for example if I clicked the entry twice, the second time the position of the cursor would be stored when I clicked the first click, and this is not what I want.

Comment: Why are you adding a TapGestureRecognizer to an Entry?  What are you trying to accomplish?  Where is the relevant code?

Comment: Tap gesture acts before cursor changed, so what you get is the previous cursor position.

Comment: I have posted a workaround, you could have a try.

Answer (score 2):

Very very bad idea.
(Focusing on event, that happens before the change.)

Assuming you have something like this in the xaml:

```
<Entry x:Name="myEntry"/>
```

you should be doing something like this in the code:

```
myEntry.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == Entry.CursorPositionProperty.PropertyName)
            Debug.WriteLine($"Cusor is at position {((Entry)s).CursorPosition}");
    };
```

If you are interested in the value of the property, you should be catching the events that are related to that property.

Answer (score 0):

Because tap gesture acts before cursor changed, when you get cursor position from **TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped**, what you get is the previous cursor position not the current cursor position.

Here I share a solution to use Task.Delay.

Suppose there is an entry in XAML,

```
<Entry x:Name="myentry">
    <Entry.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
    </Entry.GestureRecognizers>
</Entry>
```

In code behind, we set a delay after we tapped,

```
async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.TappedEventArgs e)
{
    var entry = sender as Entry;
    await Task.Delay(50);
    //After the delay, the cursorPosition should be correct
    Console.WriteLine(entry.CursorPosition);

}
```

And now we get the correct CursorPosition. If you still have any questions, feel free to ask.

Hope it helps!